# Free shipping depending on weight and on minimal cart amount

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

With WooCommerce, I need to have Free Shipping over certain amount of **250** except the heavy products that are included in the cart.

Does anyone know what i should do?

Comment: So you want free shipping for some items in the cart but not for others?

Comment: please edit your question according to [mcve]

Comment: hey there yes kinda.I need the free shipping only for the light products over 250 . I need to have the heavy products with shipping costs over the 250 limit.

Comment: Look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15457059/woocommerce-create-free-shipping-for-single-item-while-using-ups-extension/34282227#34282227 . Not exactly the same, but very similar .. should help point you in the right direction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This custom code will keep **free shipping** method and will hide other shipping methods when the cart amount is up to **250** and if products **are not heavy** (less than 20 kg here)… To not allow Free shipping for orders less than 250, you can set this in woocommerce *(see at the end).*

First you will have to sure that the weight is set in each heavy product (for simple or variables products (in each variations). The cart subtotal here is **Excluding taxes** *(and you can change it to Including taxes easily)*.

[image]

Then here is that custom hooked function in **`woocommerce_package_rates`** filter hook:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'conditionally_hide_other_shipping_based_on_items_weight', 100, 1 );
function conditionally_hide_other_shipping_based_on_items_weight( $rates ) {

    // Set HERE your targeted weight (here is 20 kg) <== <== <== <== <==
    $targeted_product_weight = 20;
    
    // Set HERE your targeted cart amount (here is 250)  <== <== <== <== <==
    $targeted_cart_amount = 250;
    // For cart subtotal amount EXCLUDING TAXES
    $passed = WC()->cart->subtotal_ex_tax >= $targeted_cart_amount ? true : false;
    // For cart subtotal amount INCLUDING TAXES (replace by this):
    // $passed = WC()->cart->subtotal >= $targeted_cart_amount ? true : false;
    $light_products_only = true; // Initializing

    // Iterating trough cart items to get the weight for each item
    foreach( $package['contents'] as $cart_item ){
        // Getting the product weight
        $product_weight = $cart_item['data']->get_weight();

        if( !empty($product_weight) && $product_weight >= $targeted_product_weight ){
            $light_products_only = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    // If 'free_shipping' method is available and if products are not heavy
    // and cart amout up to the target limit, we hide other methods
    $free = array();
    foreach ( $rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
        if ( 'free_shipping' === $rate->method_id && $passed && $light_products_only ) {
            $free[ $rate_id ] = $rate;
            break;
        }
    }

    return ! empty( $free ) ? $free : $rates;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

This code is tested and it works for simple and variable products…

> You Will also have to in WooCommerce settings > Shipping, for each shipping zone and for the **`"Free Shipping"`** method your minimum order amount:

[image]

> **You will need to refresh shipping cached data:** disable, save and enable, save related shipping methods for the current shipping zone, in woocommerce shipping settings.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time!! Will this give only the heavy items a per/kg shipping cost over the 250 while the "light" items that are included in the cart will be free shipping?

Comment: i dont understand i think sorry for that...so what will happen with the heavy items that are on the cart with the light ones?Will they have a shipping cost as i want?

Comment: Does this still work in 2022? I tried this code and I am having a strange issue, I am not able to add products to the cart. When I remove the code then I am able to add products to the cart.

Answer (score 0):

For free shipping over certain amount, you can use inbuilt WooCommerce option.

For skipping free shipping if for some specific products , you can use below snippet.

```
 add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_method_if_particular_product_available_in_cart', 10, 2);

        function hide_shipping_method_if_particular_product_available_in_cart($available_shipping_methods)
        {
            global $woocommerce;

            // products_array should be filled with all the products ids
            // for which shipping method (stamps) to be restricted.

            $products_array = array(
                101,
                102,
                103,
                104
            );

            // You can find the shipping service codes by doing inspect element using
            // developer tools of chrome. Code for each shipping service can be obtained by
            // checking 'value' of shipping option.

            $shipping_services_to_hide = array(
                'free_shipping',

            );

            // Get all products from the cart.

            $products = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

            // Crawl through each items in the cart.

            foreach($products as $key => $item) {

                // If any product id from the array is present in the cart,
                // unset all shipping method services part of shipping_services_to_hide array.

                if (in_array($item['product_id'], $products_array)) {
                    foreach($shipping_services_to_hide as & $value) {
                        unset($available_shipping_methods[$value]);
                    }

                    break;
                }
            }

            // return updated available_shipping_methods;
    return
        }
```

Comment: hey there and thanks for the snippet.I need the free shipping only for the light products over 250 . I need to have the heavy products with shipping costs over the 250 limit. Is that snippet including that?Thanks so much

Comment: free shipping for certain minimum amount can set via Woocommerce.

Comment: Heavy product ids can be added into snippet and can manage the shipping with slght modificatio

Comment: $products_array = array(
                101,
                102,
                103,
                104   you mean that one right?So adding the ids here the heavy items will only have shipping costs over 250 and the light ones will be free after i set in the wc?sorry if that sounds stupid