# Woocommerce flat rate and free shipping

Tags: woocommerce

What's the best way to set up a flat rate shipping fee up to a certain dollar amount, and then free shipping over that dollar amount? I'd like to set it up like this: $15 shipping for all items in their cart if cart is less than $50, free shipping on orders over $50. Thanks!

Comment: May be this Question code + Answer can put you on the right way (even if is not really the same problem): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42396787/shipping-calculated-on-the-items-weight-and-cart-amount

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with following way

- Config the flat rate in WooCommerce zone
- Config the Free shipping with minimum order amount $50
- Use below code snippet to hide Flate rate if the cart total is above $50

  ```
  add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_flat_rate_based_on_cart_total', 10, 3);
  function hide_flat_rate_based_on_cart_total( $available_shipping_methods, $package ){
      $price_limit = 50;
      if( WC()->cart->get_total() > $price_limit ){
          foreach($available_shipping_methods as $method_key  =>  $method){
              if ( strpos($method->method_id, 'flat_rate' ) !== false) {
                  unset($available_shipping_methods[$method_key]);
              }
          }
      }
      return $available_shipping_methods;
  }
  ```